# Magento 2 ui component form add extra input in the same admin field control

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2.2, adminform, ui-form, ui

How to add more input like checkboxes in the same area like the `use default`?

like so:
[image]

More precisely I thinks is a field service see shoot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Bellow is how achieved this!

```
<fieldset name="field_set_name" sortOrder="100">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Field Set Name</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="field_set_group" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group" sortOrder="110">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="1_field_name" sortOrder="10" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">source</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">1 Field Name</label>
                </settings>
            </field>
            <field name="2_field_name" component="Magento_Catalog/js/components/url-key-handle-changes" sortOrder="15" formElement="checkbox">
                <settings>
                    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <checkbox>
                        <settings>
                            <description translate="true">2 Field name</description>
                            <valueMap>
                                <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                            </valueMap>
                        </settings>
                    </checkbox>
                </formElements>
            </field>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkboxes as many as you want [click here how to](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-checkbox.html)